# ansible ssh connection error

Tags: ssh, ansible

can't connect with Ansible to device:

using this command:

> `ansible -m shell -a 'show version' servers`

on the device im trying to connect to from log buffer, im getting this error:

> SSH server login is insecure. (ServiceType=stelnet, UserName=edvkrs,
>   IPAddress=10.30.253.254, VPNInstanceName=*public*, Reason=Negotiated
>   key exchange algorithm is not safe.)

can you recommend any options or modifications in Ansibles SSH config ?

Thanks

thank you, after ssh -vv im getting this output:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ssh -vv edvkrs@10.46.1.1
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.46.1.1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.46.1.1 [10.46.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version -
debug1: no match: -
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.46.1.1:22 as 'edvkrs'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,sm2kep-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug2: ciphers ctos: AEAD_AES_256_GCM,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,AEAD_AES_128_GCM,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: AEAD_AES_256_GCM,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,AEAD_AES_128_GCM,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:aAiYHe0TRpg6AMTDwUYNAw4ZzgCvuOlPy8JGa8chqH0
debug1: Host '10.46.1.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/osboxes/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

**********************************************************************
* Jus esate prisijunge prie privacios irangos. Visi veiksmai,vykdomi *
**********************************************************************
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/osboxes/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
User Authentication
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Enter password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 10.46.1.1 ([10.46.1.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 131072 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

maybe from this is posible to tell how can i edit the ansible.cfg ?

Answer (score 5):

Set `ansible_ssh_common_args` and specify valid key algorithms and ciphers for your SSH server.

For example, in an inventory file

```
[servers]
10.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_common_args="-o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=aes256-cbc,3des-cbc -o MACs=hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-512"
```

You may check the output of `ssh -vv` to your device first in order to obtain supported algorithms.

You can also check if there's a module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_network_modules.html) for the device you're trying to connect.

Comment: can you retry with `-c paramiko` or `-c ssh`? you're not mentioning which ansible version you're using or what's the device you're trying to connect.

Comment: sorry, seems its connects to the device, but immediatly disconets. I created new topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887038/default-ansible-template-returns-error with question - do default module works only with CISCO ? Im trying to connecto to HUawei device, could it be a problem ? Thanks..

Comment: if that's a cloudengine device you may prefer using its [dedicated module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ce_command_module.html) instead.

Comment: This answer is correct, but the example provided in this answer has a typo - `ansible_ssh_common_arg` should be `ansible_ssh_common_args` (plural instead of singular).