# Ansible` ios_command `Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, cisco-ios

I have this command which basically is just to get the data from the device.

```
- name: Get data
  tags: get_facts
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - show version
  register: ruijie_sh_interfaces
  vars:
    ansible_command_timeout: 90
    ansible_connection: network_cli
    ansible_network_os: ios
```

But it gives me this error when running this playbook at the AWX-tower.

```
    "msg": "Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"
```

I know this device is not accessible with `ssh user@ip` which outputs:

```
Unable to negotiate with <IP> port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

BUT IS ACCESSIBLE USING `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@ip`

I want to know how to implement the `-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` using `network_cli` connection type in ansible.

Comment: So your question seems just about an [Ansible SSH connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871266/), which could be fixed by setting [`ansible_ssh_common_args`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) in your inventory.

Comment: Since you are using the `network_cli` the [Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/network_cli_connection.html#parameters) might be interesting for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the key `ansible_ssh_common_args` to the inventory of the device in AWX and check again?

```
- name: Get data
  tags: get_facts
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - show version
  register: ruijie_sh_interfaces
  vars:
    ansible_command_timeout: 90
    ansible_connection: network_cli
    ansible_network_os: ios
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o Ciphers=+aes256-cbc'
```

ref. https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/12578